# Input number manually to sql database through query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select 
    a.secCode, b.[Haircut (%)], c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)] 
from 
    openquery(PDC_MYAPPS, 'select secCode from mii.secReq') a 
left join 
    (select * from RC_Saham) b on a.secCode = b.kode 
left join 
    (select * from Absolute_IDR) c on b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
where 
    b.[Haircut (%)] is not null

union

select 
    a.code_Ic, a. PERC_HRCT, b.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)]
from 
    openquery(MANTARAY, 'select b.code_ic, a.PERC_HRCT 
                         from cminstruments a, instrument_codes b
                         where a.ID_CMI_CAPCO = b.INS_ID_INS_CAPCO') a   
left join 
    (select * from Absolute_IDR) b on a.code_Ic = b.[Kode Saham]
where 
    code_Ic in (select a.secCode 
                from openquery(PDC_MYAPPS, 'select secCode 
                                            from mii.secReq') a 
                                            left join (select * from RC_Saham) b on a.secCode = b.kode 
                                            left join (select * from Absolute_IDR) c on b.kode = c.[Kode Saham]
                                            where b.[Haircut (%)] is null)
```

I got the result:

```
 KODE    |HAIRCUT|  Absolutes IDR 
 MLIA     94.00         13                 
 SIMA     100.00        20             
 CTRA     20.00         300
 NRCA-W   100.00        NULL
 VINS     60.00         30   
 NRCA-W   100.00        NULL
```

I want to fill null value with number based on haircut value directly in the query above.

Let's say if `haircut = 100` then `absolutes IDR = 20`.

How can I make it in the SQL query?

Comment: Is "f haircut = 100 then absolutes IDR = 20." the only "rule" you have? Or is the logic more complex?

Comment: Yeah, IF...THEN would work, or CASE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: There is no ORDER in your query. Specify what does it mean "based on haircut value above". <br\> Lookup of Absolutes IDR has to be defined.

Comment: at least state the rules of the value you want to put... example like why will be 20 if haircut = 100

Comment: @Dean 45  I have the static data for that. haircut 100 then absolute IDR = 20  only one of example data. there are many more.

Comment: @Patrik Třeštík I need to define manually in querry for Absolutes IDR which it has null. I already have completed data for haircut and absolute IDR. let say Haircut = 100 then Absolute_IDR = 20 and many more. but I don't know how to define it in my query above for only null.

Comment: @Mureinik yes, thats the only rule

Comment: If your rule is fix defined, use @aucup answer bellow. It shows how to hardcode the rules.  Better solution should be to store rules in table and join it.

Comment: @Patrik Třeštík yes, but I dont know where should I put that query in my query above.

Comment: In selects replace both occurrences of `c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)]` with `ISNULL(c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)], CASE b.[Haircut (%)]
        WHEN 100 then 20
        WHEN 80 THEN 40
        ELSE 0 END )`
Exactly similar how it is in Answer.

Comment: Done! Its working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL()` and `CASE` for this:

```
select 
    a.secCode, b.[Haircut (%)],
    ISNULL(c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)], CASE b.[Haircut (%)]
        WHEN 100 then 20
        WHEN 80 THEN 40
        ELSE 0 END )
```

See [MSDN on CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) for more detail.